# How to save files on local storage received from FormData constructor ? It says "arrayBuffer" is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to save file received from client side on my local storage. Below is the server side code in node js.

```
app.post('/api/upload/media', (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, file) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: "Image could not be uploaded"
      })
    }
    if(file){
      console.log(fields)
      // const buffer = Buffer.from(file.arrayBuffer());
      // fs.writeFile("./files/image.png", buffer, (err) => {
      //   console.error(err)
      // })
    }
  })
  res.send(file.name)
});
```

console.log(file) prints this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the file object in your console, you can see a `path` property. This is the location where your file is stored on your machine. In facts, `formidable` write the file to your disk as soon as it receives it, before executing the callback of the `.parse()` method.

The good news is you can customize the directory where the files are saved this way:

```js
app.post('/api/upload/media', (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = "/you/custom/upload/folder"
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, file) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: "Image could not be uploaded"
      })
    }
    if(!file){
      // Throw an error if there is no file
    }
    res.send(file.name)
  })
});
```

The important part is this line. The file will be saved in whatever directory set the `uploadDir`

```js
form.uploadDir = "/you/custom/upload/directory"
```